# Error using `\verb` as the replace string on `\xpatchcmd`

Tags: verbatim, patching, xpatch

On this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags,regexpatch,verbatim}
\tracingpatches
\tracingxpatches
\newcommand{\test}{testone (testtwo)}
\begin{document}
\xpatchcmd*{\test}{(}{(\verb|}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\test}{)}{|)}{}{}
\test
\show\test
\end{document}
```

produces the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \verb ended by end of line.
```

and `\show\test` outputs the following:

```
> \test=\long macro:
->testone (\verb |testtwo|).
l.11 \show\test
```

It is apparent that `\xpatchcmd` introduces an extra space after `\verb`, which is taken as the start/end character to `\verb` instead of `|`.

First question: is there a way to change that on `\xpatchcmd*`?

As a workaround I switched to `shortvrb` and it works, but another problem arises when I am closer to the "real" situation. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags,regexpatch,verbatim,shortvrb}
\MakeShortVerb{\|}
\tracingpatches
\tracingxpatches
\def\test{testone (\testtwo)}
\begin{document}
\xpatchcmd*{\test}{(}{(|}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\test}{)}{|)}{}{}
\test
\show\test
\end{document}
```

As we see, these codes differs on the use of `shortvrb` and on the definition of the `\test` macro. I would expect that this string (`\testtwo`) will be taken with the verbose operator `|` but it won't.

Second question: why this behavior and how to make it work?

Comment: Do you really need `\verb`? Your one example uses `\testtwo`, the other `testtwo`.

Comment: `\verb` can not work in the argument of another command so it can't do anything useful even if you did manage to patch it in. You do not say what is the intended outcome of the change. It must be possible without using `\verb`

Comment: the space after `\verb` is not a space token in the definition it is simply an artefact of the way `\show` shows commands. the issue is that the end delimiter is patched in with incorrect catcode, but you do not need verb here.

Comment: @Werner What I call the "real" situation is when the `\test` macro includes a macro, that's why `\testtwo` and not `testtwo`. The latter was used in my first example in which using `\verb` works and it can be changed with for example `\ttfamily`, so no need to use verbatim output. The real case includes a backslash. I need that the `\test` command outputs literally the string `\testtwo` after some patches, like the first example but including the backslash.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I forgot that `\verb` can't be used as the argument of another command. Also you are right on that the space on `\show` is a visual artifact! I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your real example is actually real, then I would take from it that you want the argument between the parentheses `(`...`)` to be set in `\ttfamily`, but it contains a *single* control sequence starting with `\`. For that, the following patch provides a work-around:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\test{testone (\testtwo)}

\begin{document}

\patchcmd{\test}{(}{(\begingroup\ttfamily\string}{}{}
\patchcmd{\test}{)}{\endgroup)}{}{}
\test
\show\test

\end{document}
```

`\string` followed by a control sequence turns the escape `\` into a printable backslash. The `.log` file shows

```
> \test=macro:
->testone (\begingroup \ttfamily \string \testtwo \endgroup ).
l.12 \show\test
```

Comment: It works. `\string` does the job with `\ttfamily` enclosed inside a group. I'll adapt it to a more real situation. As you may guess, the purpose is not patching a command on the way shown in the MWE. It should work inside the documentation part of a `.dtx` to read the generated `.tex` files and parses some comments from them to take all relevant parts. I'll comment later. Thanks @Werner!

Answer (score 3):

Let's do an experiment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\test}{testone \verb|testtwo|}

\begin{document}

\show\test

\test

\end{document}
```

On the terminal you get

```
> \test=\long macro:
->testone \verb |testtwo|.
l.7 \show\test

? 

! LaTeX Error: \verb ended by end of line.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \test
```

so you see that it's not a problem with `regexpatch` and, in particular, with `\xpatchcmd`.

The fact is that `\verb` cannot be used in the argument to another command, including the replacement text of a macro.

Using `\shortvrb` doesn't help.

Comment: Ok, you are right. It is not `\xpatchcmd` problem. I forgot that `\verb` can't be used inside another command. So how can I deal with the backshash which is part of the `\test` command if I can't do `\verb` inside a command?

Comment: @EmilioLazo How to solve the problem depends on the real situation. A single control sequence can be accommodated with Werner's workaround, but more general text can't be managed that way.

Comment: Everything as expected. Now it is possible to have these macro names (like `\testtwo`) not only enclosed on parenthesis as I though, but in any place on the `\test` macro and more than one occurrence. Now should be good if `\xpatchcmd*` may catch all backslashes to substitute them with the `\begingroup\ttfamily\string` solution, given by @Werner, but in that case, the `\endgroup` primitive should be placed just after the end of that macro, i.e. when the category code of the next character is different than 11. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm using `\regexpatchcmd*{\test}{\c{[A-Za-z]*}}{\c{begingroup}\c{ttfamily}\c{string}\0\c{endgroup}}{}{}`. It works good but the search pattern matchs the macros with `A-Za-z` but if another character has the letter catcode it won't match. How can be generalized to all letter catcodes? I have no success with `\cC` and `\cL`. Also would be good adding `{}` after `\c{endgroup}` to add a blank space when needed. For example when typing `\LaTeX{}` in a document. How to do that?

Comment: Anybody can help me adding `{}` with their correct catcodes (1 and 2) at the end of the replace group on `\regexpatchcmd*`? I mean, after `\c{endgroup}` in my last comment... Please!